# Azure Storage Account failover and resetting Replication to RA-GRS?

Tags: azure, failover, azure-storage-account

I have an Azure Storage Account with RA-GRS (West US & EAST US) and I could failover using the below command

```
az storage account failover --no-wait --yes --name storageaccountName

az storage account update --name storageaccountName --resource-group rg --sku Standard_RAGRS
```

However the second command failed to execute indicating "Operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access "

As it failed SKU didn't set as Standard_RAGRS and still LRS.

How do I set the SKU to "Standard_RAGRS" after failover with "--no-wait" parameter included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--no-wait` is part of the az CLI itself, not the underlying operation. It tells az CLI to return, even before the underlying operation is finished. So your storage account failover process is probably still running - and might take a bit to complete. Before that isn't done, you cannot do another update operation on it.

Comment: Thank you, it make sense. I don't want to hold the execution until the failover rather I want to let it run in the background and want to configure the SKU post failover. How do I achieve this? Is there a way to monitor the status of the failover process, so that I can write a function periodically check and set the SKU..

Comment: `az storage account failover -n mystorageaccount -g MyResourceGroup --no-wait` 
 `az storage account show -n mystorageaccount --expand geoReplicationStats`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_failover-examples